# We've never had such a long string of unanswered questions before, what might be the reason it happened recently?

Tags: discussion, participation, unanswered-questions, specific-question

This screenshot says it all:

[image]

All these questions were bumped to the top on September 26th, and none of them have got answers. They are about VASP, LAMMPS, Quantum ESPRESSO, QMC, and TDDFT, all which are topics that are ***very highly*** on-topic here and regularly get attention.

Does anything think they have *some* insight (any insight!) as to what may have happened here? Typically when a group of unanswered questions is bumped up, several of them do get answered (this time there was only one of them answered by Tyberius, and I think all the rest of them have remained unanswered).

Comment: Is it because the questions are far from being general and are focused sharply on a specific niche.

Comment: @AnoopANair maybe you could write an answer about that, so that we can comment on your specific idea, and get feedback from the community about whether or not people think this is a significant contributor to what we've observed. Sharply focused questions didn't have trouble getting answers earlier in our site's lifetime, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any particular insight that's specific to these questions, or knowledge of the patterns of visiting traffic.  However, I have some speculations to offer. First, all these questions seem to have been asked during August-September, and then bumped on September 26th. For many, these are busy months when fiscal years change, and when teaching and other commitments start up again. This year is probably more stressful than most too...

Second, as Anoop points out in a comment, several of the questions are highly specific. In such cases, the asker relies on having the right person(s) showing up. Third, another group of the questions do seem a bit vague, and some even have "it depends" responses in the comments. In my experience, such questions can take longer to answer, either because responders feel their knowledge isn't general enough, or because it's hard to figure out what question the asker really wanted to ask. Both question categories seem to call for someone with specific expertise as well as time to figure out how to answer. Which gets us back to the first point.

That said, [this question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2226/671) seems to be another case entirely. Assuming there is such a code, an answer could be written easily and painlessly.